# 502 bad gateway error when reloading PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx

I have a problem with PHP-FPM on Debian when trying to reload PHP-FPM configuration with PHP script that runs `sudo service php5-fpm reload` which will reload the same php-fpm process on which the script is running. The problem is that I get "502 Bad gateway" on the moment when the php-fpm configuration is reloaded.

In order to reproduce the issue, run a script like following through your browser and run `sudo service php5-fpm reload` from your terminal when the script is running:

```
<?php

sleep(15);

echo 'End';
```

Is there an easy way to overcome that issue or do I need to find a solution to that problem from a different angle?

Comment: a dumb-proof and simple (but probably bad) solution will be stop receiving external request until all existing requests are resolved, update the config, then enable the service again. This assumes all you worried is that it'd break stuff mid process, and disabling the service for less than a minute isn't that critical. I'd encourage you to explain what you business concerns are and maybe someone else could tailor a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why, but changing `process_control_timeout = 0` to anything else than 0 (`process_control_timeout = 1800s`) solved the issue. Now even after reloading php-fpm I get `End` printed out on the screen.

I would be glad if anyone explained why does it actually work.

Comment: This might be of use: https://selivan.github.io/2016/10/25/php-fpm-502-error-on-reload.html